# express js not serving the static css files from router

Tags: css, node.js, express, routes

I am actually facing this problem in another bigger project but, I have made a simple one so as to explain it easily

Tree Structure of my project is as follows

```
demo
|____admin
|         |____admin.js
|____node_modules
|
|____static
|         |____bootstrap.min.css
|         |____headerStyle.min.css
|
|____views
|    |____admin
|    |    |____admin_home.ejs
|    |
|    |____partials
|                 |____admin_header.ejs
|
|____index.js
|____package-lock.json
|____package.json
```

please bear with me, I am going to post the code of some of important files

code in 'index.js' is this

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/',function(req,res)
{
  res.render('./admin/admin_home');
});

let admin = require('./admin/admin.js');
app.use('/admin',admin);

app.listen(9000,function(){
  console.log('listening to port : 9000');
});
```

Code in 'admin/admin.js' is this

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req,res)
{
  res.render('./admin/admin_home');
});

router.get('/adminhome',function(req,res)
{
  res.render('./admin/admin_home');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Code in 'views/admin/admin.ejs' is this

```
<%- include('../partials/admin_header.ejs')  %>

<h1>Admin Home</h1>
```

I am having problem with express js static file serving.

For the following URL's the webpages are rendered with all the styles from css files

```
http://localhost:9000
http://localhost:9000/admin
```

they are served from these paths

```
http://localhost:9000/bootstrap.min.css
```

and

```
http://localhost:9000/headerStyle.css
```

but for the following URL webpages are rendered with plain html with out serving the css syles

```
http://localhost:9000/admin/adminhome
```

the error is

```
Failed to load the resources: the server responded with 404
```

css files are served from these paths

```
http://localhost:9000/admin/bootstrap.min.css
```

and

```
http://localhost:9000/admin/headerStyle.css
```

and the 'Link' tags in 'vies/partials/admin_header.ejs' are as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headerStyle.css">
```

versions of the modules are as follows

```
ejs:^2.5.7
express:^4.16.2
path:^0.12.7
```

my nodejs version is
    v8.5.0

Please help me in finding the solution for this problem. Thank You

Comment: the `href` of your styles are relative to the url you are visiting. You can make them absolute like: `href="/bootstrap.min.css"`.

Comment: @RolandStarke Thanks a ton, that worked, add your solution to answers, I'll accept it.. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

as quoted by Roland Starke, the hrefs of the styles were relative to the url I was  visiting. I can make them absolute just by adding a ' / ' like

```
href="/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a line to index.js

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Comment: Thanks for considering my question,  I did what you have suggested, but still having the same problem.